# WPF Datagrid seems to keep validation error references even after a new item source

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I observed a very strange issue related to WPF DataGrid validation that occurs only in some conditions. To reproduce the issue I have a test window.

```
<Window x:Class="TEST.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TEST"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto">   
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="0" ColumnWidth="*"></DataGrid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1">Fill Data</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
namespace TEST
{
     
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ObservableCollection<Person> list = null;
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         list=   new ObservableCollection<Person>();
           
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new Person() { Age = 20, Name = "Person"+i.ToString()});
            }
            datagrid.ItemsSource = list;
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
      
    }
}
```

When I write a non numeric value for a cell under Age column, the cell gets a red border to show the error. But without correcting that error, if I populate the DataGrid with a new list the error disappears as expected.
Now, if I enter an Age cell and right click, then click another row before closing the combobox that exception is thrown:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
> element' This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.Windows.Automation.Peers.UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(System.Windows.UIElement)
> System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.CellAutomationValueHolder.TrackValue()
> System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ReleaseCellAutomationValueHolders()
> System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
> System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
> System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
> System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs,
> System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding)
> System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.Input.ICommand, bool)
> System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
> System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)

The stack trace doesn't have clear information about the issue and that exception can be raised some other cell click / edits other than the test above. The common point is that WPF DataGrid tends to keep references to previous ItemSource object especially when there are validation errors.
I have tried using other IEnumerable types and moving the ObservableCollection definition into the button click event but the result is same.

How can I clear validation error references and make the DataGrid forget about the previous ItemSource objects?

Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce. For me it's a bug in WPF framework that you should report. However, I think you can workaround it if you never set your list to null nor reset it instead but initialize it as a private member like this: `readonly ObservableCollection<Person> list = new ObservableCollection<Person>();` and just call `list.Clear();` instead of newing it in `Button_Click` as you're pulling the rug out from under WPF's feet.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, this seems a promising workaround. I believe changing the itemsource leaves orphaned event listeners which may be a reason for groving memory usage through the app life-cycle.

Comment: @aliassce The memory is managed by the garbage collector. Your abandoned collection will be garbage collected when it becomes eligible. The negative performance impact of replacing the ItemsControl.ItemsSource is really critical and should always be avoided.

Comment: @BionicCode I agree, the GC will handle unused list and clearing and adding items to the existing ItemsSource is a better practice. However it's a common scenario to use same the same DataGrid for different list types. So, it seems impossible to avoid that issue.

Comment: @SimonMourier your observation is right. It is because of the nature of ObservableCollection. The list is used as reference to the ItemSource and when the list is nulled the itemSource is also nulled, and in parallel it should have triggered an on change event and framework tried to update the view but doing this it found itemSource as null and instead of updating the view it just thrown the exception.

Please excuse for my bad English.

Comment: Did you try using binding? I would rarely allow a user to edit directly in a datagrid but I have done a couple of simple views worked that way. I'd bind itemssource to an observablecollection property. Presenting a new set of data, i'd usually build a new observablecollection from a list and replace to previous one.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the idea, I haven't tried it but I'm not sure if it will solve the issue.   As Simon pointed keeping the original list seems to be a suitable workaround.

Comment: The column.DataGridOwner owner seems null. https://source.dot.net/#PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,6889